# Importance of using sails-linker in Sails.js development?

Tags: javascript, linker, gruntjs, sails.js

What is the importance of using the `sails-linker` grunt tasks when developing in the development environment?

When I run `sails lift --verbose`, a lot of time is spent in `sails-linker`. I would think I would only want to minify and link in `production` where I would want that efficiency; not in `development`.

I could be totally confused on what `sails-linker` does, so please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm looking to be educated on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of sails-linker is to define how your JavaScript and CSS files are injected into your frontend, in both development AND production, but the process is different.

When you `sails lift`, `tasks/register/default.js` is run, and when you `sails lift --prod`, `tasks/register/prod.js` is run

In development: 
If you look in `tasks/pipeline.js`, you will see `var cssFilesToInject` and `var jsFilesToInject` arrays. sails-linker (by default) injects 'jsFilesToInject' into any .ejs files between `<!--SCRIPTS--><!--SCRIPTS END-->` and any 'cssFilesToInject' between any `<!--STYLES--><!--STYLES END-->` tags.

So instead of having to manually link styles or scripts, if you include them in the right array in tasks/pipeline.js, sails will do it for you when you lift the server.

In production: 
Simply, things are minified, then injected.